# How can i solve this problem using recursion?

Tags: programming-languages, recursion, functional-programming, matrix

```
I have already solve this problem using forloop.
Given an nxn matrix A. Here n is number of row and column. Write a recursive function to find the sum of the diagonal elements of A. 
Example:
  3  2 1
  6  3 4
  9 8  3
Output 9




#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int mat[12][12];
    int i,j,row,col,sum=0;
    printf("Enter the number of rows and columns for 1st matrix\n");
    scanf("%d%d",&row,&col);
    printf("Enter the elements of the matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&mat[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("The matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //To add diagonal elements
    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        {
            if(i==j)
            {
                sum=sum+mat[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("The sum of diagonal elements of a square matrix = %d\n",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you're asking for an algorithm, since coding questions are generally off-topic here (you might want to try StackOverflow instead).

Remember that the diagonal elements of a matrix $M$ are $M_{ii}$ for all $i$. This makes the algorithm very similar to summing a list (i.e. taking the sum of $A_i$ for all $i$).

A recursive algorithm for summing a list would look something like this, in pseudocode:

```
function ListSum(A):
    n ← A.length
    if n = 0: return 0
    else: return A[1] + ListSum(A[2..n])
```

Can you see how this could be adapted to your matrix problem?